# Can't show String array item in textArea

Tags: java, arrays, string, jtextarea

I can't seem to work out why the method `display()` won't display the array values in `stringList`. I have made the array global but that doesn not change the result.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        display();
    }

private void display(){
    String[] stringList = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    ArrayText.setText("");
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
        ArrayText.append(stringList[n] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `ArrayText`?

Comment: ArrayText is a JTextArea. The program compiles correctly but when the JButton is pressed nothing appears in the JTextArea

Answer (score 0):

stringList's size is 5. You are calling stringList[n] with n greater than 4 which is illegal.

Use instead:

```
for (int n = 0; n < stringList.length; n++){
```

Comment: I've done what you suggested but when the JButton is pressed the JTextArea (ArrayText) still remains blank instead of displaying the array text. The progam compiles OK so not sure what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do `repaint()` on ArrayText:

```
private void display(){
    String[] stringList = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    ArrayText.setText("");
    for (int n = 0; n < stringList.lenght; n++){
        ArrayText.append(stringList[n] + "\n");
    }
    ArrayText.repaint();
}
```

Also, remember about Paco suggestions about stringList.lenght